# Reading second line of textfile and adding to datagridview

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to add items from a textfile to datagridview but I only want to add the items from the second line of the textfile and Im not sure how to achieve this.
Thanks

```
        Dim rowvalue As String
        Dim cellvalue(20) As String



        Dim streamReader As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(OrderID.txt)

        While streamReader.Peek() <> -1
            rowvalue = streamReader.ReadLine()
            cellvalue = rowvalue.Split(","c)
            dgvOutput.Rows.Add(cellvalue)
        End While
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways but I think this is the simplest.

```
Dim textfile As New StreamReader("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Testfile.txt") 'open file
textfile.ReadLine() 'read a line and do nothing with it
dgvOutput.Rows.Add(textfile.ReadLine) ' read another line and add it to dgv
```

Comment: See my comment on the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\OrderID.txt")
        Dim LinesList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        Do While Not reader.EndOfStream
            LinesList.Add(reader.ReadLine())
        Loop
        reader.Close()
dgvOutput.Rows.Add(LinesList(1)) '1 is the second items from OrderID.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. And if I want to split the data in the textfiles based on where there is a " , " , how would I do that. Thanks again.

Comment: Then you do something like this https://www.dotnetperls.com/split-vbnet

Comment: A StreamReader needs to be not closed but disposed. From the docs. "This type implements the IDisposable interface. When you have finished using the type, you should dispose of it either directly or indirectly. " https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a stream reader to do this. Just System.IO.File class.

Using the index starting with one effectively skips the first line of the text file.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\OrderID.txt")
    For index = 1 To lines.Length - 1
        Dim cells = lines(index).Split(","c)
        dgvOutput.Rows.Add(cells)
    Next
End Sub
```

The small c at the end of .Split indicates the comman is a Char not a string as .Split is expecting a Char here.